# Poisson's equation in 2D: Find analytical expresions of $f(x, y)$ so that the exact solution is $u_0(x,y) = 10x + \tanh(10x-10)$

Tags: partial-differential-equations, poissons-equation

Given the Poisson's equation

$$-\nabla^2 u(x,y) = f(x,y) \in \Omega$$

$$u = u_0(x,y) \in \partial \Omega$$

with $$\Omega = [0,1]^2$$

I want to derive the analytical expression of $f(x,y)$ so that the exact solution is

$$u_0(x,y) = 10x + \tanh(10x-10)$$

Could you please give just a **hint** on how to do this?

I have only studied separation of variables for the heat equation during my course.

Comment: Have you try Fourier series?

Comment: No. The problem is that we did the very first example of solving PDE with separation of variable this Friday and we are not confident enough to use this technique. But apparently professors do not care about that... I do not where to start from. Thank you.

Comment: Your desired exact solution is denoted the same as the boundary condition function ($u_{0}$) and is independent of $y$.  Is all this correct?

Comment: I asked the same question to the TA, and he replied "yes"... Still confused. I am not bale to use separation of variables in this case. Is there any other way? Because we started doing this example before covering PDE theory.

Comment: Wait, so you're given the boundary data, and you're asked which Poisson PDE the function satisfies? If so, then there are probably many answers to this. One answer that would work is if you just assume that $u(x,y) = 10x+\tanh(10x-10)$ (just like the boundary data), calculate $-\nabla^2u(x,y)$, and set $f(x,y)$ equal to that.

Comment: In fact I am trying to do that. Because I do not think I have to use any technique to **solve** the equation... Thank you.